# Is there a way to find if a commit/sha present on remote Git server without cloning

Tags: git, gerrit, git-ls-remote

At the moment I use `git ls-remote` to check if a some changes are present on Gerrit server. But not all changes are can be checked is way, particularly merges which do not appear in `git ls-remote` output.

How can I check if a change is present on Git server without cloning the repo. I'm aware `git -r --contains` can be used from within the repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `gerrit` is among the tags, I assume you are using Gerrit.

For a commit which has been pushed for review (`refs/for/foo`), you can use [gerrit query](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-query.html) or [Query Changes](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/rest-api-changes.html#list-changes) to check if it's on the server.

For any commit, if you have access to the Gerrit server and you know the repository name, you can use `ssh` to run git commands (`git rev-parse` or `git log`) on the Gerrit repository.

```
ssh $username@$gerritserver git --git-dir=$path_to_repo.git rev-parse $commit
```

Comment: Was able to use this on Gerrit mirror but, with Gerrit server I got, `fatal: "--git-dir" is not a valid option`